# HTTP request inside iOS AppIntent

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I can't figure out how to make an AppIntent where the result is the response of an http-get request.

Here is what I have so far, but since the `performHTTPGet` function is asynchronous, I don't know how to get the response from it inside the `perform()` function.

```
struct HttpGet: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Get API Result"
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        performHTTPGet(for: "https://my-server-api")
        return .result(dialog: "API response should be here")
    }
    
    private func performHTTPGet(for url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("HTTP GET Response: \(responseString)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an `URLSession.dataTask(with:)` with use the `async`, so you might want to rewrite it there?

Comment: You should watch "Meet async/await" you are mixing completion handlers with the new Concurrency.

Comment: thanks guys for taking me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments took me in the right direction.
Here is how I solved it using async/await:

```
struct HttpGet: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Get website text"
    
    @Parameter(title: "Website", description: "Website", requestValueDialog: "Enter website")
    var website: String

    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        do {
            let response = try await fetchWithAsyncURLSession(for: website)
            return .result(dialog: "\(response)")
        } catch {
            return .result(dialog: "Failed to get server response.")
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchWithAsyncURLSession(for url: String) async throws -> String {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return "Invalid URL."
        }

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

        if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            return responseString
        }
        return "Invald server response."
    }
}
```